# Dividing all elements in a multidimensional array by an array of numbers Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a python question:

If I have a multidimensional array lets say shape (3,4) and a 1D array with 3 values that for example look like this:

```py
profile = np.array([[1,2,3,5],[3,6,2,5],[2,8,3,5]]) 

radius = np.array([4,8,3])
```

I am looking for a way to divide all values from the first/second element of my multidimensional array by the corresponding first/second number of the 1D array. So as an output I would basically something like:

```
profile_new = np.array[[1,2,3,5]/4], [[3,6,2,5]/8], [[2,8,3,5]/3]
```

I tried:

```py
for i,j in zip(radius_prof, r_500):
    radius = i/j
```

But this yields an array only consisting of 4 elements, but I want again a multidimensional array with shape (3,4).

I hope my question is understandable, this is my first post here and I could not find any similar question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `profile/radius[:,None]`? or `profile.T/radius` depending on the desired shape

Comment: Ah yes that actually works! Can you explain this maybe? Would really hep me for further understanding :)

Comment: @alaskagirl [Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: First one forces broadcasting, second one aligns the shapes for the correct operation

Answer (score 0):

You need to `append` results to a list in `for`:

```
import numpy as np

profile = np.array([[1,2,3,5],[3,6,2,5],[2,8,3,5]])
radius = np.array([4,8,3])


result = []
for i,j in zip(profile, radius):
    result.append(i/j)

result
```

#### By [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) :

```
result = [x/y for x,y in zip(profile,radius) ]
```

#### A better way :

```
result = np.divide(profile.T, radius).T
```

#### Output:

```
[array([0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.25]),
 array([0.375, 0.75 , 0.25 , 0.625]),
 array([0.66666667, 2.66666667, 1.        , 1.66666667])]
```